# Updating automatically an HTML content when the imported *.json values are changed

Tags: html, json

I have an HTML code that imports a **LOCAL** but **UPDATABLE** *.json content, and it must be updated automatically when the *.json file is updated.

This is the ***.HTML** code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="sample.json"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" >

            function load() {

                setInterval(function () {

                var mydata = JSON.parse(data);
                var div = document.getElementById('data');

                div.innerHTML = mydata[0].location.altitude;

            }, 100);}

        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="load()">
        <div id="data">

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

and the **adapted sample.json** file is:

```
data = '[{"location": {"altitude": 40}}]';
```

I just wanna see the **altitude** is changing in the browser(HTML) whenever the **sample.json** file is updated.

Now the HTML works but only **ONCE**, I wanna make it dynamic.

What should I do to make the function **setInterval** work correctly? or maybe this function works only for local changes, not external ones.

Thnks, Sadeq

Comment: "and the sample.json file is" — That's JavaScript, not JSON. Don't give it a `.json` file extension.

Comment: I didn't get your point, but this is exactly a JSON file, not a Javascript code.

Comment: `data = '[{"location": {"altitude": 40}}]';` is not JSON. It is JavaScript. If it was JSON it would be **just** `[{"location": {"altitude": 40}}]`

Comment: Ups, so that I did since it was mentioned that accessing a local *.json file from HTML is forbidden due to securities, so you must touch the file to make it accessible. I didn't know this make it js!

Answer (score 0):

If you want the browser to get data from a URL even interval, then you need to write code which *gets data from a URL* in the interval. e.g. with [the Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch). (At which point you should make it JSON instead of JS).

**However** HTTP is not fast. You do not want to be polling over HTTP every 100ms. Consider using [Websockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API) to push the data from the server when it changes instead of polling.

Comment: Thanks, Quentin.
The *.json file is locally stored with a high frequency in my PC.

Comment: **FETCH** function does NOT work for me,
***Uncaught TypeError: Failed to fetch***

Comment: If you want to poll data or use websockets then you need an environment that will let you do that. Add a web server to your project.